# Comparison between two ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

What is the best way to handle Java ResultSet? I'm creating a Desktop application that will connect to an oracle database using JDBC.

However, I am having problem with handling ResultSets since I can't do comparison using for loop.

```
// create a database connection object
DB db = new DB();

// get rows of my first table and second table
ResultSet firstRS = db.getMyFirstTable();
ResultSet seconRS = db.getSecondTable();

// compare the two tables
while(firstRS.next()) 
{
    // get the row of my first table
    String firstRSRow = firstRS.getString("col1");

    while(secondRS.next()) 
    {
        // get the row of my second table
        String secondRSRow = seconRS.getString("col1");

        // compare row from first table to the row in second table
        if(firstRSRow.startsWith(secondRSRow))
        {
            // do some processing here....
        } // end if
    } // end while
} // end while
```

I know that this could be accomplish with [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) with a few lines of code but I don't have the luxury of time to study it.

I also found commons [DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/index.html) from apache but it seems complicated for me as a novice programmer.

Is there other way/tools/libraries/framework simple enough to get ResultSet from databases and manipulate it in simple and straightforward manner?

I will also appreciate if you could direct me to a website that has sample codes concerning java database connectivity.

Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Why `ResultSet`? You could easily compare values with `SELECT` statement. In case you still want to ResultSet then think about [CachedRowSet](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/JDBCTutorial/chapter5.html).

Comment: @user692533 - It is better to populate the List<T> for specific the column and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB db = new DB();

 // get rows of my first table and second table
ResultSet firstRS = db.getMyFirstTable();
ResultSet seconRS = db.getSecondTable();

// compare the two tables
while(firstRS.next() || secondRS.next()) 
{
// get the row of my first table
String firstRSRow = firstRS.getString("col1");
String secondRSRow = seconRS.getString("col1")

    // compare row from first table to the row in second table
    if(firstRSRow.startsWith(secondRSRow))
    {
        // do some processing here....
    } // end if
} // end while
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean resultset(String SQL1, String SQL2){
    public boolean status=false;
    ResultSet ViewResultset = st.executeQuery(SQL1);
      ResultSet QueryResultset = st.executeQuery(SQL2);

      while (QueryResultset.next() | ViewResultset.next())
      if (ViewResultset.getRow() == 0   | QueryResultset.getRow() == 0) {
      break;
      } else {
         for (int i = 1; i < ViewResultset.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("OOO"+ QueryResultset.getMetaData().getColumnCount());
            String columnName = ViewResultset.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
      System.out.println("ColumnName :" + columnName);
    for (int j = 1; j < QueryResultset.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1; j++)
    if (ViewResultset.getMetaData().getColumnName(i).equals(QueryResultset.getMetaData().getColumnName(j))&& !(QueryResultset.getString(columnName) == null || ViewResultset.getString(columnName) == null))
    if (ViewResultset.getString(columnName).toUpperCase().contains(QueryResultset.getString(columnName).toUpperCase())) {
        System.out.println(" Actual "+ ViewResultset.getMetaData().getColumnName(i)     + " Expected: "+ ViewResultset.getString(columnName));
        status=true;

    }      
    else {System.out.println(" Actual "+ ViewResultset.getMetaData().getColumnName(i)     + " Expected: "+ ViewResultset.getString(columnName));
    }
    }
    }
    return status;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ResultSet is a subclass of Object ultimately and we can compare two or more objects directly. A little specific to your question:

```
 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql1);
 ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery(sql2);
```

where sql1 and sql2 are 2 Statements

```
 while(rs.next() && rs1.next()){
     int a=rs.next();
     int b=rs1.next();
     if(a==b){
          System.out.println("Compairing two ResultSets");
     }
 }
```

Comment: rs.next() returns boolean not an int

Comment: #Shilan. Are you crazy?. I was sharing the way to do. Not for coding statements.

Comment: I believe you haven't realized rs.next() concept. When you check if rs.next(), you have already moved the pointer in front of record, by calling it again you move pointer forward and you skip first record! Moreover if you want to compare rs1 and rs!! You should know that they are objects and cannot be compared like ==. Basically I don't see any correct statement in this code!

Comment: #Shilan. Do you think you are so smart?. May be you are a blind. If you think you are a smart, just give your answer for this question. Do not point to others.

Comment: i am smart enough not to answer when I know nothing of that :D